# Images not showing up for django-simple-captcha

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I am using django-simple-captcha to make a captcha for different contact buttons on a webpage. I think I have it all working except for the fact that the images for the captcha [won't show up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T8dI.png)

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_landing, name='product_landing'),
    url(r'(?P<product_slug>.*)/?$', views.product_detail,            
    name='product_detail'),url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls'))
]
```

html for page:

```html
</form>
{% else %} {% if is_valid %}
<div style="margin-top: 70px; margin-bottom: 200px;">
  <h1 style="margin-bottom: 25px">Thank you!</h1>
  <p style="font-size: 17px; line-height: 32px;;">Your resume has been received and we will be in touch with a decision soon. Please contact us if you have any questions.</p>
</div>
{% else %}
<form action="" method="POST" id="apply-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="application-form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="firstname {% if form.first_name.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>FIRST NAME</p>
    {{ form.first_name }}
  </div>
  <div class="lastname {% if form.last_name.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>LAST NAME</p>
    {{ form.last_name }}
  </div>
  <div class="email {% if form.email.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>EMAIL</p>
    {{ form.email }}
  </div>
  <div class="phone {% if form.phone.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>PHONE</p>
    {{ form.phone }}
  </div>

  <div class="resume-container {% if form.resume.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>ATTACH PDF RESUME</p>
    <input class="readonly" type="text" READONLY>
    <div class="resume">
      {{ form.resume }}
      <div id="browse">
        <a>BROWSE</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="message {% if form.message.errors %}form-error{% endif %}">
    <p>MESSAGE</p>
    {{ form.message }}

  </div>
  {{ form.captcha }}
  <button class="submit-button" type="submit">
                                            APPLY
                                        </button>
</form>
```

I've updated my forms and settings according to the documentation so I don't think that's the issue. From what I know so far I figure that it has to have something to do with the imaging libraries but I'm not quite sure. I have Pillow 4.1.1 installed and I'm on a Mac if that helps.

Comment: What entries does your webserver access log have for those image requests?

Comment: Ah i forgot to mention that I'm running this for development on my own system and haven't pushed these changes over to the webserver yet.

Comment: But you still have _some_ kind of web server running on your local machine, even if it's just the django development web server, right?

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood your question mb. [errors](http://imgur.com/a/9Zfom)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles across this, I figured it out. I had to list the captcha url above the product url because it was looking for the image in the wrong place.

Comment: It's still not working for me.

This is what my urls.py looks like
urlpatterns = [ 
    
    path(r'captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    #path("404/", custom_page_not_found),
    #path("500/", custom_server_error),
    path('', include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]